# Wrap a function whose parameters are struct and int using swig

Tags: c, ruby, swig

I have spent couple of days to figure out how I can wrap a C structure but so far no success.

This is the C function I have:

```
abc_return_t
       abc_method (abc_context ** context,
          int set_from_os)
```

`abc_context` is a structure. What should I write in the `interface(.i)` file so I can pass the `**` context from Ruby? Right now I am able to use `my_module.abc_method(nil,1)` and get the results but I am not able to pass the context. When I pass context params like `my_module.abc_method(context,1)` I get the error `Expected argument 0 of type abc_context **, but got String "context"`.

I looked at other Stack Overflow questions and most of them point to a direction where I can create a struct doing something like `my_module.name_of_struct()`. Unfortunately that is not working for me. Right I have not written anything in the .i file for swig to wrap functions.

Here is the `abc.i` file:

```
%module my_module
%{
  #include "/usr/local/include/abc.h"
%}

 %include "/usr/local/include/abc.h"
```